# apply condition on json file and fetch the value and append the output in bash

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I have a `jq` which fetches the particular value from the json file and append the output to a text file. Text file contains the [OPTIONS] NAME for Eg: `docker-virtual.artifactory.com`.

So the output should go and append as a **RepositoryName:TAG** to the existing one in the text file.

```
  "dependencies": [
  {
   "name": "powershell-core",
   "type": "zip",
   "path": "Dependencies",
   "filename": "PowerShell-Core-6.2.3-win-x64.msi"
  },
  {
   "name": "redis",
   "type": "docker-image",
   "path": "redis:6.0.10-alpine3.12",
   "filename": ""
  },
  {
  "name": "keycloak",
  "type": "docker-image",
  "path": "jboss/keycloak:12.0.1",
  "filename": ""
  },
  ]
```

From this Json file I am fetching the value with the type as `docker-image`
and redirecting the values to a file `output.txt`

```
jq -r '.dependencies[] | select(.type == "docker-image").path' packages.json > output.txt
```

So the `output.txt` file looks like:

```
redis:6.0.10-alpine3.12
jboss/keycloak:12.0.1
```

But I am trying to append this output to a file like:

```
        docker-virtual.artifactory.com/redis:6.0.10-alpine3.12
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: If the text file does not already end with a newline character, use `>>` instead of `>` to append to it, and let jq prepend its output with a slash, e.g. using: `"/" + select(...)`.

Comment: @pmf  Ok so can I use it like : `jq -r '.dependencies[] | "docker-virtual.artifactory.com/" + select(.type == "docker-image").path' packages.json > output.txt `

Comment: As I understood, `docker-virtual.artifactory.com` was already the content of the text file to which you wanted to append the output of the jq call. But if you want to create your file from scratch anyway, sure, that could work.

Comment: _From this Json file_ : the provided file content above this expression is not a valid JSON value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
jq -r '.dependencies[] | select(.type == "docker-image").path' packages.json |  sed 's/.*/docker-virtual.artifactory.com\/&/'> output.txt
```

Note this will rewrite output.txt file every time, if your only intention is to append to it then use the '>>' sign like so:

```
jq -r '.dependencies[] | select(.type == "docker-image").path' packages.json |  sed 's/.*/docker-virtual.artifactory.com\/&/'>> output.txt
```

Hope this helps.